# How to display contents of a dictionary into web page using Flask

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have this problem where I can't display the contents of a dictionary into a webpage.

```
 web_indiv[url_sequence] = {'url' : converted_url , 'name' : x.name, 'count' : web_count_current }

    return render_template('video.html', web_data = web_indiv)
```

The *web_indiv* is populated using a loop, and then passed to video.html as web_data.

Sample dictionary

```
{1: {'url': 'http://www.drpeppersnapplegroup.com/', 'name': 'Dr. Pepper-Snapple Group', 'count': 57}, 2: {'url': 'http://www.rccolainternational.com/', 'name': 'Royal Crown Cola', 'count': 41}}
```

Note: It is a dictionary that contains another dictionary inside it.

This is what I already have on my html file.

```
{% for key1,line in web_data.items() %}
     {% for key2,line_item in line.items() %}
     <tr>
        <td class="col-md-2">{{ line_item['url'] }}</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">{{ line_item['name'] }}</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">{{ line_item['count'] }}</td>
    </tr>
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Data won't display on the webpage.

Thank you for taking time to read my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just a dict, you could try this:

```
<html>
{{web_data[url_sequence]}}
<table>
    <tr>
        {%for value in web_data[url_sequence].values()%}
          <td class="col-md-2">{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Note that the `web_data[url_sequence]` is a dictionary.

This one will have the orders (url, name and then count):

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{ web_data[url_sequence].url }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{ web_data[url_sequence].name }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{ web_data[url_sequence].count }}</td>
</tr>
```

Real example:

Suppose you have the dictionary `web_indiv`, then you want to render it to template `video.html`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def root():
    web_indiv = {}
    url_sequence = 'test'
    web_indiv[url_sequence] = {'url':'testabc','name':'hello','count': 4}
    return render_template('video.html', web_data = web_indiv, url_sequence = url_sequence)
```

Then you can use the dict in template like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{ web_data[url_sequence].url }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{ web_data[url_sequence].name }}</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">{{ web_data[url_sequence].count }}</td>
</tr>
```

The html will show you:

```
testabc hello 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. But do I have to pass the value of url_sequence to the html as well?

Comment: @JeremyCenteno you can refer the real example (updated in answer) to let you understand how to use the dict in template.

Comment: @JeremyCenteno as you can see the above example, you have to pass variable url_sequence into template, so that the dictionary can work.

Comment: Hi. What if, say url_sequence is  an integer and it's value increase by one every single time the dictionary is being populated with new data, should I also have a loop inside my html(using Jinja2) that would increment so that I can iterate through the whole of the dictionary?

Comment: no need to do that in template, template receive the data and present it, you can do that in backend, and pass the dictionary with matched key url_sequence.

Comment: Thank you very much. It really made me understand dictionaries, jinja2 and flask.

Answer (score 1):

```
 {% for key2,line_item in web_data[url_sequence].items %}
     <tr>
        <td class="col-md-2">{{ line_item }}</td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. But Jinja2 throws an UndefinedError. Btw, I  forgot to include a sample of the dictionary that the loop produces. As of this writing, sample dictionary has been added.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16224168)